# Add additional character filter to regular expression

Tags: regex

I have regular expression which is checking for at least one character or number:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$
```

I want to add one more condition there to exclude forward slash:

I know that to exclude forward slash would be something like that [^/]  but i don't know how exactly put it to my regex.

May be someone may help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[^/]*$
```

That's all there is to it.

The dot `.` means "any character". The `*` repeats the previous token 0 or more times. So

```
[^/]*
```

means "zero or more non-slash characters", whereas

```
[^/].*
```

means "one non-slash character, followed by zero or more characters of any kind".

Comment: i tried like that but didn't took out the comma `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[^/].*$` , what comma means?

Comment: the last dot, this one before `$`, I quoted how i was trying to exclude forward slash

Comment: hehe, me as well, i mean dot not comma :)

Comment: when i leave the dot after `[^/]` this dot means what?